# Dealing with textarea height crossbrowser

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to absolute position a button underneath a textarea, I have some content next to the button I'd like to have it not push down.

```css
html {
  background: #1f252e;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.commentForm {
  position: relative;
}
.textInput {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.textInput__input {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}
.textInput:hover {
  cursor: text;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
.formField.hasErrors .wd-input {
  border-color: #e43e22;
}
.wd-form__footer {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
}
.formField__error {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #e43e22;
}
.wd-button--primary {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 35px;
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.wd-button {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wd-form__status {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.commentForm__actions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="commentForm wd-form">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="formField hasErrors" style="max-width: 100%;">
      <div class="textInput wd-input ">
        <textarea rows="3" class="textInput__input" placeholder="Type a comment..."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="formField__error">15 more characters to go...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wd-form__footer">
      <div class="wd-form__status">
        <div class="formStatus"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="commentForm__actions wd-form__actions">
        <a role="button" class="wd-button wd-button--primary">
          <div class="wd-button__label">Post comment</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, in Firefox and Chrome I get very different results.

In Chrome the button is aligned properly:

[image]

But in firefox, the button is clipping with the textarea:

[image]

This is because the text area height is different in Firefox than it is in Chrome. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to stay away from `position: absolute` if I can. You can instead use `float: right` and a negative margin.

```css
html {
  background: #1f252e;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.commentForm {
  position: relative;
}
.textInput {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.textInput__input {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}
.textInput:hover {
  cursor: text;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
.formField.hasErrors .wd-input {
  border-color: #e43e22;
}
.wd-form__footer {
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.formField__error {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #e43e22;
}
.wd-button--primary {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 35px;
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.wd-button {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wd-form__status {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.commentForm__actions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="commentForm wd-form">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="formField hasErrors" style="max-width: 100%;">
      <div class="textInput wd-input ">
        <textarea rows="3" class="textInput__input" placeholder="Type a comment..."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="formField__error">15 more characters to go...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wd-form__footer">
      <div class="wd-form__status">
        <div class="formStatus"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="commentForm__actions wd-form__actions">
        <a role="button" class="wd-button wd-button--primary">
          <div class="wd-button__label">Post comment</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't help when `formField__error` is going to push it down, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Are you able to change the HTML code?

Comment: No. I cannot do that.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Actually, why is `formField_error` going to push it down, surely it is not as it is already present?

Comment: Should have explained myself better, this is a HTML snapshot from an application I am developing, the error is not always there. It appears if there is validation errors in a form field.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Yes, but in my solution, if you delete `formField_error`, the button still stays in the same place.

Comment: that's because you're still using the absoute positioning in your answer code.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Ok, sorry. I misunderstood the issue. If the issue is just to do with the `textarea` height, surely you can change this in CSS or by using `rows`?

Comment: I am using rows. I've somehow fixed it by making "fake" rows. Now when I set the rows in my javascript code, it simply takes the number of rows, then multiplies it with 15 px.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you should edit the question or open a new one as this is slightly different to what the question appears to be asking, especially seeing as you're now talking about JS which you haven't included.

Comment: I just said I fixed it... I'm gonna answer my question myself and choose that as the correct answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to find a simpler "test case" that illustrates your problem because there is a lot of code here, and some behind the scenes you're now telling me about.

Comment: Sorry, that's great then